# How to call a function AFTER blur from input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using **jquery-ui datepicker** as one of my inputs. If a user blurs from an input, I display a relevant message (e.g. "This field is required"). For this purpose I have the following jQuery, which works perfectly fine for simple `<select>` and `<input type="text">` tags:

```
$("input").blur(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="")
        $(this).next().text("This field is required.");
    else
        $(this).next().text("");
});
```

However, in case of datepicker (where I have to *essentially* **blur** to select a date) the error message gets displayed *even after* I've selected the date (i.e. selection of date is leading to the blur event). This requires that the `.blur(function(){});` should be called **after** the blur event is completed (not simultaneously).

How to solve this situation?

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/95/).

Comment: Like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/98/**

Comment: Or this - http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/99/ though `adeneo` suggestion is much better!

Comment: @adeneo yes! that's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: also, how can I call onClose() of datepicker explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add your validation check to the onClose event of the datepicker, rather than the blur event of the input field:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    if(!selectedDate) {    
        $(this).next().text("This field is required.");
    }
}});
```

Comment: would be really helpful if you could tell me how to call close function of date explicitly :)

Comment: would be really helpful if you could tell me how to call onClose explicitly from another function :)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a hack, but you could just delay the check with `setTimeout`:

```
$("input").blur(function () {
    var $t = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        if ($t.val() == "") $t.next().text("This field is required.");
        else $t.next().text("");
    }, 100);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/96/

Comment: Thought of that, but that would lead to setTimeout() for every other input, that's not what I was looking for.

Comment: also I don't want a separate handler for this input alone.

Comment: You are going to have to get a little more refined than a shotgun `$("input")` selector and use the custom datepicker event.